# mxGraph change the Layer ordering of cells

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm using mxGraph and trying to create an overview of the layers/cells. The user should be able to change the order of these layers.

Atm I have only seen that it's possible to send a cell to the top layer and to the back. Are there any specific methods to send a child one layer back or forth?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be too late.

I solved it by sorting the root's children directly with the sort method.

```js
graph.model.root.children.sort(function(firstLayer, secondLayer) {
  // Your rules
});
```